# Missing HDF5 C++ Library, How to solve?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, path, hdf5

I am now trying to run a software called ViennaTS. (at /ViennaTS/build)

```
cmake ..
```

This produced the following error code.

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5")
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5")
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.74.0", minimum required is "1.46.0")
-- Found SPRNG: /home/ishitanaken23/sprng/lib/libsprng.a
-- Found HDF5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_cpp.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so (found version "1.10.7") found components: CXX
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:69 (message):
  Missing HDF5 C++ library
```

PC cannot find the HDF5 C++ library.
The description of HDF5 in CMakeList.txt is as follows: HDF5_hdf5_cpp_LIBRARY is not found.

```
# HDF5
FIND_PACKAGE(HDF5 COMPONENTS CXX)
IF(HDF5_FOUND)
  IF(HDF5_hdf5_cpp_LIBRARY)
    add_definitions(-DUSE_HDF5)
    add_definitions(${HDF5_DEFINITIONS})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    SET(LIBRARIES ${LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_LIBRARIES})
  ELSE(HDF5_hdf5_cpp_LIBRARY)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Missing HDF5 C++ library")
  ENDIF(HDF5_hdf5_cpp_LIBRARY)
ELSE(HDF5_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "Missing HDF5 library: ViennaTS will be built without TDR file support")
ENDIF(HDF5_FOUND)
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me find a solution.　Thanks.

CMakeCache's description of HDF5 is as follows.

```
//HDF5 CXX Wrapper compiler.  Used only to detect HDF5 compile
// flags.
HDF5_CXX_COMPILER_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/h5c++

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_crypto:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_curl:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_dl:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_hdf5:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_hdf5_cpp:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_cpp.so

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_m:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_pthread:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_sz:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so

//Path to a library.
HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_z:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so

//HDF5 file differencing tool.
HDF5_DIFF_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/h5diff

//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for HDF5.
HDF5_DIR:PATH=HDF5_DIR-NOTFOUND
```

The path to the file, which is the HDF5 C++ library, is set correctly.

Comment: Looks like the project you build expects that `FIND_PACKAGE(HDF5 COMPONENTS CXX)` will set variable `HDF5_hdf5_cpp_LIBRARY` to the path of C++ HDF5 library. But [FindHDF5.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindHDF5.html) scripts actually sets variable `HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_hdf5`. BTW, [there](https://github.com/viennats/viennats-dev/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L89) they use different logic about HDF5 library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I solved the problem by replacing the part of HDF5 description in CMakeList with the part of HDF5 in CMakeList of ViennaTS-dev. Thank you.